# Is there any way to execute some R code inside a "cat()" function inside a chunk in a R Markdown document?

Tags: r, automation, r-markdown, inline

Can anyone help me out?
I have to automate some reports, with R Markdown, of the company I work for.
To do so, I have to create headings with the names of forest gardens, deppending on the forest gardens that were evaluated last month.
The problem is that the numbers of forests gradens evaluated every month is not the same.
So, I added a condition to run on chunk option "eval" to create that heading deppending on the number of the evaluated forest gardens (it's ok until here). 
To do so, I wrote this code:

````
```{r eval = cond_n1, results = 'asis'}
cat('<h4 class = "hortos"> 4.1. `r unique(tabela_por_talhao$NM_HORTO[1])`</h4>')
```#end
````

But when I knitr the document every thing works very fine, but the inline code that I inserted in this heading doesn't, it prints the code literatelly (without execute).
Is there any way to do what I want? 
OBS: I only added the "#end" to the end of the chunk because otherwise it won't show here the whole code.

Comment: Dose this work? `cat('<h4 class = "hortos"> 4.1.', unique(tabela_por_talhao$NM_HORTO[1]), '</h4>')`

Comment: @DarrenTsai , thanks a lot! It worked very well. I knew it was something simple, but since I'm getting started with R and R Markdown there are some basics that I don't know veru well.

Comment: Just to add a comment, I see you said you are creating monthly reports, in Rmarkdown, you can have 1 file and have each R chunk have `r month.name[2]` where 2 is the month, and then inside that chunk, have the report that runs that month.

Comment: @DanielJachetta , thanks for the tip. I didn't know that. In my code to choose the month of report, I created a vector containing the names of months and used ```r month_of_flight <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), '%m')) - 1``` and then I used the number that "month_of_report" variable received to find the corresponding value to the name of the month. It worked better for me this way because I'm from Brazil and my reports have to be written in portuguese and the code ```r month.name[x] ``` returns the name of month in english.